# Why aren't my turtles breeding?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently made a turtle breeding farm in Minecraft survival mode and when ever I bred the pair of turtles all I got was experience points and that’s it, they did not lay eggs and yes the farm was next to the ocean and there was sand for the turtles to lay their eggs.

Comment: How did you get these turtles?  Have you trapped them in any way?

Comment: Turtles have some unusual conditions and behaviours for breeding, you can't just put them into a pen somewhere and feed them stuff. Look here: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Turtle#Breeding

Comment: Archive link for my last comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Turtle&oldid=1260727#Breeding

Comment: It can't be just random sand - it must be a Beach biome. Press F3, check the 'Biome' entry.

Answer (score 6):

Your farm needs to be on the "home beach" (the beach on which they spawned/hatched) of the turtles you breed. So you either have to base your farm around the turtles or find a couple turtle eggs, pick them up with silk touch and bring the to your farm, and wait for them to hatch.

Answer (score 1):

They take a minute to actually lay the eggs after breeding, it could also be because you are not on their home beach, in which case find turtles that are based on a beach near you

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that at least one of the turtles needs to be one its original beach home, but the other turtle can be from a different beach home.